# Using updateOne method to update an object field inside array - throws error "Cannot create field 'url' in element"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert-update

I have MongoDB database (with Mongoose) containing a collection of Products (among others), which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Product A',
    url: 'product-a',
    category: 'accesory',
    price: 12,
    shortDescription: ['example description'],
    technicalSpecs: [{ speed: 10, weight: 20 }],
    images: [],
    reviews: [],
    relatedProducts: [
      {
        url: 'product-b',
        name: 'Product B',

        // to be added in Update query
        //id: id_of_related_product
      }
    ]
 } /* other Product objects */
```

]

As every MongoDB document is provided with `_id` property by default, but within the `relatedProducts` array i only have `url` and `name` properties, i want to add the `id` property (associated with corresponding Product) for each object in the `relatedProducts` array, so i will be able to conveniently query and process those related products.

I came up with an idea to query all Products to get only those, which have non-empty `relatedProducts` array. Then i loop them and i search for Product model, which has specific `url` and `name` properties - this let's me get it's *true* (added by MongoDB) `_id`. At the end i want to add this `_id` to matching object inside `relatedProducts` array.

My code:

```
async function assignIDsToRelatedProducts(/* Model constructor */ Product) {
  const productsWithRelatedOnes = await Product.find(
      { relatedProducts: { $ne: [] }}, ['relatedProducts', 'name', 'url']
  );

  for (const productItem of productsWithRelatedOnes) {
    for (const relatedProduct of productItem.relatedProducts) {
      const product = await Product.findOne(
        { url: relatedProduct.url, name: relatedProduct.name }, 
        '_id'
      );

      // throws error
      await productItem.updateOne(
        { 'relatedProducts.url': relatedProduct.url },
        { $set: { 'relatedProducts.$.id': product._id } }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

However it throws the following error:

> MongoError: Cannot create field 'url' in element {relatedProducts: [ /* array's objects here */ ]}

I don't know why MongoDB tries to **create field 'url'**, as i use it to project/query `url` field (not create it) in `updateOne` method. **How to fix this?**

And - as i am newbie to MongoDB - is there a simpler way of achieving my goal? I feel that those two nested `for..of` loops are unnecessary, or even preceding creation of `productsWithRelatedOnes` variable is.

Is it possible to do with [Mongoose Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)? I have tried it, but i couldn't match virtual property within the same Product Model - attach it to each object in `relatedProducts` array - after calling `.execPopulate` i received either an empty array or `undefined` (i am aware i should post at-the-time code of using Virtual, but for now i switched to above solution).

Answer (score 0):

Although i didn't find solution or even reason of my problem, i solved it with a slightly other approach:

```
async function assignIDsToRelatedProducts(Product) {
  const productsHavingRelatedProducts = Product.find({ relatedProducts: { $ne: [] }});

  for await (const withRelated of productsHavingRelatedProducts) {
    for (const relatedProductToUpdate of withRelated.relatedProducts) {
      const relatedProduct = await Product
        .findOne(
          { url: relatedProductToUpdate.url, name: relatedProductToUpdate.name },
          ['url', '_id']
        );

      await Product.updateMany(
        { 'relatedProducts.url': relatedProduct.url },
        { $set: { 'relatedProducts.$.id': relatedProduct._id } }
      );
    }
  }

  const amountOfAllProducts = await Product.find({}).countDocuments();
  const amountOfRelatedProductsWithID = await Product
    .find({ 'relatedProducts.id': { $exists: true } }).countDocuments();

  console.log('All done?', amountOfAllProducts === amountOfRelatedProductsWithID);
}
```

Yet, i still suppose it can be done more concisely, without the initial looping. Hopefully somebody will suggest better solution. :)